# Paraview: some pipeline settings from python script not reflected in the UI

Tags: python, scripting, paraview

I am scripting Paraview (5.6.0) in Python, creating spherical glyphs from a VTU file. Relevant part of the script is shown below. After the script finishes, the glyphs are created and shown with proper parameters but the UI is not reflecting all the settings.

More specifically, the script says `sphGlyph.ScaleArray=['POINTS','diameter']` and the view is correctly displaying spheres scaled by the `diameter` array; the UI nevertheless still says `No scale array` (in the image below). If I click "apply", I lose the `diameter` setting and the view updates to `No scale array`.

Some other settings, like `sphGlyph.ScaleFactor=1.`, are respected both in the UI and in the view.

I don't see any obvious difference between the script and Python trace when constructing the pipeline by hand.

Where is the problem?

```
# ....
vtuFile="/tmp/burnt.vtu"
view=GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
# ...
sph=XMLUnstructuredGridReader(FileName=[vtuFile])
RenameSource(vtuFile,sph)
sphGlyph=Glyph(Input=sph,GlyphType='Sphere',GlyphMode='All Points')
sphGlyph.ScaleFactor=1.
sphGlyph.ScaleArray=['POINTS','diameter']    ### <---- SET HERE
sphGlyph.GlyphType.ThetaResolution=32
sphGlyph.GlyphType.PhiResolution=32
sphGlyphShow=Show(sphGlyph,view)
sphGlyphShow.Opacity=0.5
sphGlyphShow.BackfaceRepresentation='Surface'

view.Update()
```

[image: state after loading paraview]

**EDIT:** This is the script suggested by @MatthieuWespthal (and downloaded [cube.vtu](https://data.kitware.com/api/v1/file/5afd936e8d777f15ebe1b4f3/download) which fails to set `Scale Array` correctly:

```
from paraview.simple import *
cubevtu=XMLUnstructuredGridReader(FileName=['cube.vtu'])
glyph1 = Glyph(Input=cubevtu,GlyphType='Arrow')
glyph1.OrientationArray = ['POINTS', 'No orientation array']
glyph1.ScaleArray = ['POINTS', 'f1']
glyph1.ScaleFactor = 0.1
glyph1.GlyphTransform = 'Transform2'
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')
glyph1Display = Show(glyph1, renderView1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make sure to call UpdatePipeline before creating the glyph.**

The following works perfectly with this [dataset](https://data.kitware.com/api/v1/file/5afd936e8d777f15ebe1b4f3/download).

```
from paraview.simple import *

# find source
cubevtu = FindSource('cube.vtu')
cubevtu.UpdatePipeline()


# create a new 'Glyph'
glyph1 = Glyph(Input=cubevtu,
    GlyphType='Arrow')
glyph1.OrientationArray = ['POINTS', 'No orientation array']
glyph1.ScaleArray = ['POINTS', 'f1']
glyph1.ScaleFactor = 0.1 
glyph1.GlyphTransform = 'Transform2'

# Properties modified on glyph1

# get active view
renderView1 = GetActiveViewOrCreate('RenderView')

glyph1Display = Show(glyph1, renderView1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the MWE. I added screenshot with your MWE above, it does the same: setting ``f1`` is not reflected in the UI and will disappear when "Apply" is pressed.

Comment: Make sure to call UpdatePipeline() before creating the glyph.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! :))) Can you stress it in your answer, for those reading later? Cheers!